# Multidimensional Arrays and Observable Collection

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, mvvm, observablecollection

I've seen many `ObservableCollection<T>` examples of a 2-dimensional object, but I'm working with a multi-dimensional object.

The [Faith Life Church Daily Bible Reading API](http://www.flcbranson.org/api/dailybiblereading/?begindate=2016-02-01&enddate=2016-02-05) will produce the JSON data, below (this is shortened, for brevity)...

```
{
    "dailychapter": [{
        "date": "2016-02-01",
        "book": "Esther",
        "chapter": 7,
        "verses": [{
            "number": 1,
            "text": "So the king and Haman came to banquet with Esther the queen."
        }, {
            "number": 2,
            "text": "And the king said again unto Esther on the second day at the banquet of wine, What is thy petition, queen Esther? and it shall be granted thee: and what is thy request? and it shall be performed, even to the half of the kingdom."
        }]
    }, {
        "date": "2016-02-02",
        "book": "Esther",
        "chapter": 8,
        "verses": [{
            "number": 1,
            "text": "On that day did the king Ahasuerus give the house of Haman the Jews' enemy unto Esther the queen. And Mordecai came before the king; for Esther had told what he was unto her."
        }, {
            "number": 2,
            "text": "And the king took off his ring, which he had taken from Haman, and gave it unto Mordecai. And Esther set Mordecai over the house of Haman."
        }]
    }, {
        "date": "2016-02-03",
        "book": "Esther",
        "chapter": 9,
        "verses": [{
            "number": 1,
            "text": "Now in the twelfth month, that is, the month Adar, on the thirteenth day of the same, when the king's commandment and his decree drew near to be put in execution, in the day that the enemies of the Jews hoped to have power over them, (though it was turned to the contrary, that the Jews had rule over them that hated them;)"
        }, {
            "number": 2,
            "text": "The Jews gathered themselves together in their cities throughout all the provinces of the king Ahasuerus, to lay hand on such as sought their hurt: and no man could withstand them; for the fear of them fell upon all people."
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have a class, for the JSON, with this structure (classes generated by [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com))...

```
    public class Verses
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
    public class DailyChapter
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string book { get; set; }
        public int chapter { get; set; }
        public List<Verses> verses { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<DailyChapter> dailychapter { get; set; }
    }
```

I have some level of background in databases, so my initial idea is to use `ObservableCollection` as a flat database, like so...

```
date        book        chapter versenumber versetext
"2016-02-01"    "Esther"    7   1       "So the king..."
"2016-02-01"    "Esther"    7   2       "And the king..."
"2016-02-02"    "Esther"    8   1       "On that day..."
"2016-02-02"    "Esther"    8   2       "And the king..."
"2016-02-03"    "Esther"    9   1       "Now in the..."
"2016-02-03"    "Esther"    9   2       "The Jews gathered..."
```

My ObservableCollection's class is structured as such...

```
    public class BibleReadingCollection
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string book { get; set; }
        public int chapter { get; set; }
        public int versenumber { get; set; }
        public string versetext { get; set; }

        public BibleReadingCollection(string _date, string _book, int _chapter, int _versenumber, string _versetext)
        {
            date = _date;
            book = _book;
            chapter = _chapter;
            versenumber = _versenumber;
            versetext = _versetext;
        }
    }
    // create a collection (like an array) for the binding data to be added to
    public static ObservableCollection<BibleReadingCollection> biblereadingcollection = new ObservableCollection<BibleReadingCollection>();
```

My intention is to use this ObservableCollection to feed the UI of my app in a Master/Detail type of scenario (master being the date/chapter and detail being the series of verses).  Theoretically, the master list could be populated by some form of LINQ statement and clicking on one of the chapters would fire another LINQ statement that would populate the detail list with verses.

My question is whether this is the right way to think about ObservableCollections (like a flat database).  Maybe it would be better to have each day (and, thusly, each chapter) as a single record (row) and somehow nest the verses within that record.  I'm not sure if that's even possible (can you stick an ObservableCollection or array within an ObservableCollection?).  I know, in SQL-land, you can join tables so that you don't duplicate so much data.  Then, you can create a query that would output what looks like a flat database.

What do you guys think?  I'm a very amateur developer, so a lot of these concepts are new to me.

Comment: My suggestion is first that you look into json.net because they have the ability to convert json to classes.  The goal is to get a IEnumerable of what you want to dispaly in easiest manner.  Make sure you use LINQ where needed as that will be your filtering agent.  From there once you get the list of items you want simply convert to OC like this :  var oc = new ObservableCollection(mylist).  Make sure you set up your bindings correctly and then don't overlook the power of CollectionViewSource as this gives you a superb ablity to allow user to filter at will.

Comment: @JohnPeters Thanks for the suggestion.  I do use Json.NET, but that's not really relevant to the topic.  Working with the JSON isn't the issue.  It's, really, how `ObservableCollection` should be handled (and if that's even the best option to use).

Comment: Yes ObservableCollections are perfect for XAML applications